# Toggle sort order in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a variable for sort order of the items in a model:

```
@State private var sortOrder = SortDescriptor(\ToDo.createdDate, order: .reverse)
```

I want to sometimes sort the items with .reverse and sometimes with .forward.

So I created an image and want that image to respond to a tap gesture. If the sort is .reverse, then I want to change it to .forward. If it's .forward, change it to .reverse.

But I can't just check for the value of sortOrder like this:

if sortOrder == .reverse {
...
} else {
...
}

I get this error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SortDescriptor'

How can I check on the value of a SortDescriptor object in an if statement?

Comment: have you tried using:
 `if sortOrder == SortDescriptor(\ToDo.createdDate, order: .reverse) { ...}`

Answer (score 1):

`SortDescriptor` has a few variables and to get the `order` you have to use `sortOrder.order`

```
if sortOrder.order == .reverse {
    //Reverse
} else {
    //Forward
}
```

You can use it for an `Image` something like

```
Image(systemName: sortOrder.order == .reverse ? "backward" : "forward")
```

You can create a `toggle` function and a computed variable to simplify your `View` code.

```
extension SortOrder {
    var isReversed: Bool {
        self == .reverse
    }
    mutating func toggle() {
        self = self.isReversed ? .forward : .reverse
    }
}
```

A simple `View` would look something like.

```
struct SortAnimation: View {
    @State private var sortOrder = SortDescriptor(\ToDo.createdDate, order: .reverse)
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: sortOrder.order.isReversed ? "backward" : "forward")
            .onTapGesture {
                sortOrder.order.toggle()
            }
    }
    struct ToDo {
        let createdDate: Date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the sort descriptor computed based on a simple state:

```
@State private var isReversed = true //  Define a toggle

private var sortOrder: SortDescriptor<ToDo> { //  Make this computed
    SortDescriptor(
        \ToDo.createdDate,
         order: isReversed ? .reverse : .forward //  Check the order here
    )
}
```

So toggle the `isReversed` when you need, like:

```
.onTapGesture { isReversed.toggle() }
```

And you can check on that instead:

```
if isReversed { ... } else { ... }
```